# Menubar fadein fadeout with Jquery (results not as expected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a fadeout fadein effect with jQuery:

When I hover over a link in the menu bar, a div is showing with some content inside, but when I hover the div, all tables inside that div are showing, except the one that was displayed first. How can I prevent that from happening?

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFxB7/9/) page to show you.. The effect works when you hover over "Nud" and "Crepes"

**html**

```
<body>
  <div class="escondido">
    <ul id="speise">
       <li><a id="frueh" href="">Frühstück</a></li>
       <li><a id="sup"   href="">try1</a></li>
       <li><a id="sal"   href="">try2</a></li>
       <li><a id="nud"    href="">Nud</a></li>
       <li><a id="crep"  href="">Crepes</a></li>
       <li><a id="sueß"  href="">try5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <div id="front">
        <table id="probe1">
            <tr>
                <td>something somthing else</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="probe2">
            <tr>
                <td>house</td>
                <td>world</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

**css**

```
#probe1, #probe2 {
             display: none;
         }

          #front {
          display:none;
          position:relative;
          height:600px;
          width:100%;
          background-color:lightblue;  

        }

      .escondido{
        position:relative;
        background-color:lightyellow;
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
      }

      #speise a{
        padding:10px;
      }

      #speise{
        position:relative;
        padding:10px;
      }
      #speise li{
        display:inline;
      }

      ul#speise a:hover{
        background-color:lightblue;
      }
```

**javascript**

```
$("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#front, #probe1").stop().fadeIn();   

         }, 

            function(){
            $("#front, #probe1").stop().fadeOut();
    });


    $("#nud, #front").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#front, #probe2").stop().fadeIn();   

         }, 

            function(){
            $("#front, #probe2").stop().fadeOut();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this will help you

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/3D8bd/)

But the jquery has increased in size

```
$("li a").hover(function(){
   $("li a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#front").stop().fadeIn(); 
    if($("#crep").hasClass('active')){
      $("#probe1").css('display','block');
    }
},function(){
     $("#front").stop().fadeOut();
    $("#probe1").css('display','none');
});

$("#nud, #front").hover(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#front").stop().fadeIn();
     if($("#nud").hasClass('active')){
      $("#probe2").css('display','block');
    }
},function(){
     $("#front").stop().fadeOut();
    $("#probe2").css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide visible tables on hover.

```
$("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#probe2").hide();
    $("#front, #probe1").stop().fadeIn();    
}.....
$("#nud, #front").hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#probe1").hide();
    $("#front, #probe2").stop().fadeIn();
}......
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DFxB7/10/)

Comment: thanks!.. that helped to prevent displaying everything in the div but now its fixed to only one option.. so in this case when you go over the div Nud its works fine but when you go over crepes the nud table is displayed and not crepes table